# Build c program with Maven?

Tags: c, maven, native, native-maven-plugin

I have a maven project where I'm building a docker image (using the fabric8 docker-maven-plugin).

As part of the build, I want to compile a simple C class:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    setuid( 0 );
    system( "/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates");
    return 0;
}
```

into a binary that will be copied into the Docker image during the maven build.

What's the best way to do this? I know of at least a couple of maven plugins, but not sure which I should use, and what options I need? The maven build could be running on Windows, Linux or Mac, but the resulting binary will only be executed on Linux (Opensuse).

https://www.mojohaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/

https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin

For example, the above 2 plugins seem to require the `<packaging>so</packaging>` or `<packaging>nar</packaging>` element at the top level of the pom.xml, but my pom.xml already has a `<packaging>pom</packaging>`? Should the above plugins maybe go into a maven submodule project in their own pom.xml?

Comment: Why are you making this as a C program when it could be just a simple command or at worst a shell script?

Comment: Maven is intended for Building/packaging etc. of Java code but not for C code I strongly recommend not to do such things. The question is why do you need a C program to call things like that? Can be done during the docker image creation without the need for compiling things etc. Need more details and context.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  It is a binary and not a script because the setuid flag will be set on it, and the setuid flag has no effect on scripts: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369